# Mongoose findOne is not working for a particular query, yet working for others

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I am trying to work with a `mongoDB` using `mongoose`, here is an example element from the db:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "59bc026679f3a71ed02e4812"
  },
  "name": "Le Ruban blanc",
  "customID": 80074,
  "description": "Un village protestant de l'Allemagne du Nord à la veille de la Première Guerre mondiale (1913/1914). L'histoire d'enfants et d'adolescents d'une chorale dirigée par l'instituteur du village et celle de leurs familles : le baron, le régisseur du domaine, le pasteur, le médecin, la sage-femme, les paysans... D'étranges accidents surviennent et prennent peu à peu le caractère d'un rituel punitif. Qui se cache derrière tout cela ?",
  "poster": "http://sokrostream.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/1367017617_face.jpg",
  "genres": [
    "Drame"
  ],
  "country": "Français",
  "releaseYear": 2009,
  "quality": "DVDRip"
}
```

I am using mongoose for my queries, but the following query returns null.

```
collection.findOneAndUpdate({ "customID": 80074 }, { $inc: { "views" : 1 } }, cb)
```

Please note that when I use anything other than `customID`, it works. For example the following query does work.

```
collection.findOneAndUpdate({ "name": "Le Ruban blanc" }, { $inc: { "views" : 1 } }, cb)
```

I hope you can see the problem, I have just started using `mongoDB` & `mongoose` a few days ago so the mistake might be something very basic. Any help is much appreciated!

As asked, here the Schema:

```
new mongoose.Schema({
name: {type: String, required: true},
customID: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
description: {type: String, default: 'No description available'},
poster: {type: String, default: 'default'},
genres: {type: [String], default: ['Unknown']},
country: {type: String, default: 'Unknown'},
releaseYear: {type: Number, default: 2000},
quality: {type: String, default: 'HD-720p'});
```

and here is the full mongoose code:

```
collection.findOneAndUpdate({"customID": 80074},
    { $inc: { "views" : 1 } },
    {projection: projection},
    (err, element) => {
        if (err) return res.status(400).send(err);
        res.status(200).send(element);
    });
```

Comment: Can you show mongoose code

Comment: @AzoulayJason do you mean the schema? if so then it's pretty much the same as the example object. As for the code that calls the db here it is:

    collection.findOneAndUpdate({"customID": 80074},
        { $inc: { "views" : 1 } },
        {projection: projection},
        (err, element) => {
            if (err) return res.status(400).send(err);
            res.status(200).send(element);
        });

Comment: I guess he is asking for mongoose schema definition, Please add your mongoose definition for the above collection. like this:  http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html

Comment: @RaghavGarg I edited my question with the relevent code snippet, please let me know if I need to add something else.

Comment: @RaghavGarg Thank you very much, my bad I should've verified the schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your schema you have `customID: {type: String}`. Whereas you are trying to find an `integer` in it.

Please change the type of the `customID` to `Number` like `customID: {type: Number}`.

Defining your schema correctly is very important. [Read more about schema type](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html)